# If $P = NP$ why is it not the case that for every oracle $A$, $P^{A} = NP^{A}$?

Tags: complexity-theory

I am trying to understand why the above is not the case. In my understanding, if $P = NP$ I can replace a deterministic machine with a non-deterministic and vice-versa. Hence, I will always have the exact same computational tool ...

Comment: I guess $NP^R$ would be equivalent to $RE$. Which is trivially not equivalent to $P^R=R$.

Comment: I see, can you elaborate a bit, $RE$ I am not familiar with

Comment: http://cse.ucdenver.edu/~cscialtman/complexity/Role%20of%20RELATIVIZATION.pdf This paper explains why sometimes relativization fails. TL;DR: it has something to do with how different computations models and oracles are defined.

Comment: You should read this mathoverflow question and top answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75890/definition-of-relativization-of-complexity-class